# PROBLEMA CON RUTA

Tags: rutas

perdonen la ignorancia pero esta dando este error (el cual no me carga correctamente la pagina) les dejo imagen y codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

RUTAS

```js
Route::get('/alumnos', function () {
    return view('Alumnos.alumnos');
});

//creacion de alumnos y su vista
Route::get ('/createAlumno', 'AlumnosController@vista');
Route::post ('/createAlumno', 'AlumnosController@createAlumno');
//obtenemos los datos de la tabla
Route::get ('/alumnos','AlumnosController@verAlumnos');

//editar Alumno

Route::get('/edit/{usuario}', 'AlumnosController@edit')->name('alumno.editar');
Route::put('update/{usuario}', 'AlumnosController@update')->name('alumno.update');
```

CONTROLLER

```js
    public function edit ($id)
    {
        
        $usuario = alumnos::where('id',$id)->get();
        return view('Alumnos.edit', ['usuario' => $usuario]);
        //return view('Alumnos.edit', compact('usuario'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que tu problema no es la ruta, ya que por lo que veo te cargan las funciones, tu problema es netamente con los estilos y los archivos javascripts
si usas blade solo tienes que traerlos ejemplo:

```html
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

si ya tienes una pagina con los estilos puedes usar:

```html
@extends('layouts.master')
```

para heredar los estilo, espero que te sirva, pero te vuelvo a mencionar tu problema no es con las rutas de las funciones, es con las rutas de los estilos y archivos javascript

Comment: Gracias por tomarte le tiempo de responder, al prinicipio pense lo mismo amigo, revise el @extends...y esta todo bien, cuando abro cualquier otra pagina me abre sin problemas, el problema es que en la URL al llevar eso '/edit/{usuario}'  rescato la id del usuario y eso es lo que no me permite que no me carge la pagina, de lo contrario si en la URL solo coloco 'local../edit' me carga el formulario sin problemas